# Prevent and correct numpy arrays from being nested rather than multidimensional

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Sometimes when creating new 2d arrays I end up with *nested* arrays rather than proper multidimensional ones. This leads to a number of complications such as misleading `array.shape` values.

What I mean is I end up with

```py
array([array([...]), array([...])], dtype=object)
```

when I want

```py
array([[...], [...]])
```

I'm not sure at which point in my code leads to the former scenario. I was wondering 1. what is good practice to avoid obtaining such arrays, and 2. any pragmatic fixes to revert it to the multidimensional form.

Regarding the latter, performing

```py
np.array([list(i) for i in nested_array])
```

works but doesn't seem practical, especially if the dimensionality is higher.

Comment: Unless you are intentionally creating nested/ragged arrays, there is something wrong with the lists or arrays that you are starting with.  They need to be consistent in size.  If they differ, you either get the `ragged array` warning or an error.  `[a.shape for a in nested_array]` should tell you the shapes.

Comment: Once you have a object dtype array, applying `np.stack` (or `vstack`) may change it to multidimensional array - provided all component arrays match.  It in effect treats the array as a list of arrays.  If the shapes aren't consistent, this will raise an error - which may be useful information.  Also this only applies to 1d object dtype arrays.  If this doesn't help, you may need to ask a new question with details about how you create the problem array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of arrays, for example:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.empty(3,object)
arr1[:] = [np.arange(3), np.arange(3, 6), np.arange(6, 9)]
repr(arr1)
```

Result:

```
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8])], dtype=object)
```

Note the `dtype` there. That may be causing some of your trouble, compare:

```
arr2 = np.array([np.arange(3), np.arange(3, 6), np.arange(6, 9)])
print(arr2)
print(arr2.dtype)
```

Result:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
int32
```

To turn `arr1` into an array just like  `arr2`, which is what you are asking about:

```
arr3 = np.stack(arr1)
print(arr3)
print((arr2 == arr3).all())
```

Result:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
True
```

So, make sure your arrays have the datatype you need, and if you cannot avoid ending up with an array of arrays, combine them with `numpy.stack()`.